# How to co-ordinate database access in an Android application?

Tags: android

What is the best way to pass data(which is in database class) from one activity to another activity.
I have use **cursor** but it given me error when i press back button

```
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.technosoft.listia/com.technosoft.listia.ListiaTabbar}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.technosoft.listia/com.technosoft.browserTab.FirstTab}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.technosoft.listia/com.technosoft.browserTab.BrowserCategoryList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3607)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-20 16:41:02.443: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

you have any idea?

Comment: I have used "cursor" means what you want to say? give more description.